# Keep Dropbox authentication in memory for futur use IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, root, dropbox-api

I've created a root app for IOS in Cydia. Dropbox integration is in my application, everything is fine, link account, upload, download etc...

I need to keep in memory the user authentication because everytime my app is closed, if I need to do one thing related to Dropbox I need to relink my app to my Dropbox account. 
The issue is that if Dropbox application is installed, my application is closed for Dropbox opening and after successful authentication my app is reopened. Because of the close/reopen actions, the authentication is not taken in count by my app...
If Dropbox application is not installed, everything is fine because an UIWebView is openned into my app, so the authentication is done when my app is open and it's taken in count !

So my question is how can I keep in memory the user authentication even if it's done when my app is closed ?
Or alternatively how can I force the Dropbox authentication to be done in the UIWebView instead of the application ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I would try saving an NSDictionary to NSUserDefaults with a bool "isAuthenticated" as the key and another nested dictionary as the value containing the user name and password.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202105865-Keep-Dropbox-authentication-in-memory-for-future-use-IOS ]